# Woocommerce order by seller name or author name

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, invoice, orders

I have the following code and I need to display order data based on seller id or seller name:

```
$filters = array(
    'post_status' => 'published',
    'post_type' => 'shop_order',
    'posts_per_page' => 200,
    'paged' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'modified',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'author' => $seller_id,
    'post_parent' => $order_id
);
$loop = new WP_Query($filters);
while ($loop->have_posts()) {
    $loop->the_post();
    $order = new WC_Order($loop->post->ID);
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $key => $item) 
    {
        $red = $item['product_id'];
        $_sku     = get_post_meta( $red, '_sku', true );
    }
}
```

The above loop is not showing any sku or price on the invoice section.

How to display order details on author ID (or seller name)?

Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please clarify your question to make it as minimal and clear for everyone. Maybe you may be interested in [this documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is the **`post_status`** here: For WooCommerce Orders "published" post_status doesn't exist. The available status for WooCommerce Orders are for example:

- '`wc-cancelled`'
- '`wc-completed`'
- '`wc-custom-status`'
- '`wc-on-hold`'
- '`wc-pending`'
- '`wc-processing`'
- '`wc-refunded`'

You can have different order statuses in an array…

Also **`'post_parent'`** is can't be the order ID as it always have a **`0`** value

To finish since WooCommerce 3+ Order items are now a WC_Order_Item_Product object (and you need to use available methods to access the properties values).

Last thing, to get the user ID from the user name, you can use WordPress function [**`get_user_by()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/).

So your code will be:

```
$args = array(
    'post_status' => array( 'wc-completed' ), //  <===  HERE
    'post_type' => 'shop_order',
    'posts_per_page' => 200,
    'paged' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'modified',
    'author' => $seller_id
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);

while ($loop->have_posts()) {
    $loop->the_post();
    $order_obj = wc_get_order($loop->post->ID);
    foreach ($order_obj->get_items() as $item_id => $item_obj)
    {
        $item_data = $item_obj->get_data(); // Accessing WC_Order_Item_Product object protected data
        $product_id = $item_data['product_id']; // Product ID
        $product_sku = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_sku', true ); // SKU

        // Just for Testing output
        echo "Product ID is $product_id - Sku is $product_sku<br>";
    }
}
```

This code is tested and works for WooCommerce 3+

---

Helpful Answer: [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)

Comment: Sorry, I am getting zero as output.

Comment: Actually I need to get the order based on seller id. Here post_author field.

Comment: @NavasFazil I know and I have understood. I always test my code before answering and it just works with the `post_author` ID… Try to replace `$seller_id` by a number corresponding to one of your Sellers IDs in this `WP_Query` and you will see that is working. ALso you have to go in your database in wp_post table to be sure that the `post_author` column is set with the correct Seller IDs for the related `post_type` as `shop_order`…